# GWT RequestFactory: how to handle entities with composite primary keys

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Can RequestFactory handle composite primary keys?

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html) mentions that entities must implement `getId()`; how should this be implemented in the case where entities do not have a single "id" field, but rather have multiple foreign key fields that together constitute a composite primary key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In GWT 2.1.1, the Id and Version properties may be of any type that RequestFactory knows how to transport.  Basically, any primitive type (`int`), boxed type (`Integer`), or any object that has an associated Proxy type.  You don't have to reduce a composite id to a String yourself; the RF plumbing can take care of composite keys automatically by using the persistent id of an entity-type key or the serialized state of a value-type key.

Using the previously-posted example:

```
interface Location {
  public String getDepartment();
  public String getDesk();
}

interface Employee {
  public Location getId();
  public int getVersion();
}

@ProxyFor(Location.class)
interface LocationProxy extends ValueProxy {
  // ValueProxy means no requirement for getId() / getVersion()
  String getDepartment();
  String getDesk();
}
@ProxyFor(Employee.class)
interface EmployeeProxy extends EntityProxy {
  // Use a composite type as an id key
  LocationProxy getId();
  // Version could also be a complex type
  int getVersion();
}
```

If you can't reduce the identity to a single `getId()` property on the domain type, you can use a [`Locator`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/Locator.html) to provide an externally-defined id and version property. For example:

```
@ProxyFor(value = Employee.class, locator = EmployeeLocator.class)
interface EmployeeProxy {.....}

class EmployeeLocator extends Locator<Employee, String> {
  // There are several other methods to implement, too
  String getId(Employee domainObject) { return domainObject.getDepartment() + " " + domainObject.getDesk(); }
}
```

The DevGuide linked from the question is a bit out of date with respect to
[RequestFactory changes in 2.1.1](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactory_2_1_1)

Comment: It should be mentionned that the composite ID *must* be mapped as a ValueProxy (LocationProxy in the code above), and that proxy must be exposed somewhere in the proxies (i.e. reachable when you walk the interfaces and methods starting from the GWT.create()d RequestFactory; in the sample code above, it's reachable from the getId on EmployeeProxy).

Comment: Oh, and BTW, the version doesn't have to be exposed on the proxy.